# Coordinator Layout - Let view stick underneath expandable header

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I have two toolbars in my layout, one that expands and one underneath it. Under this toolbar I have my scrollable layout. Layout looks like appended.

Currently I have the second toolbar in the scrollable layout, this means, if I scroll in the scrollable layout, the second toolbar will vanish underneath the main toolbar. I tried already a view things, but could not get following behaviour:

The second toolbar (it's the `share_dialog_search_toolbar` layout in my example) should ALWAYS stay underneath the main toolbar, no matter if the main toolbar is expanded or not. Can anyone show me how this can be achieved?

*I want something like a second header, that sticks underneath the expandable toolbar.*

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/background_material_light"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- this toolbar should always be visible underneath the main expandable toolbar in every state -->
    <include layout="@layout/share_dialog_search_toolbar" app:layout_behavior=".behaviour.SubHeaderBehaviour" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvData"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

                <ProgressBar
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/pbLoading"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:indeterminate="true" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

With following `SubHeaderBehaviour`:

```
public class SubHeaderBehaviour extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<LinearLayout>
{
    public SubHeaderBehaviour(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, LinearLayout child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof AppBarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, LinearLayout child, View dependency)
    {
        // always move child under dependency... does not work though
        child.setY(dependency.getY() + dependency.getHeight());
        return true;
    }
}
```

This behaviour does not work at all, the view just stays on top always...

**EDIT**

Sorry, this IS working with the custom behaviour. The problem was, I was using merge in my search toolbar layout. Directly adding it works like a charm. i just have to additionally adjust the padding of the scrolling view to leave the space of my sub header.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/share_dialog_search_toolbar" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: I'm quite sure I tried this. I will try it again later. But I need this to work with the search toolbar AND the scrolling view underneath...

Comment: if this didnt work try wrapping the share_dialog_search_toolbar with a framelayout

Comment: This all fails. It won't stay under the toolbar if the scroll view is scrolled... No matter how I set it up. i think, I must either use a custom behaviour or some kind of anchor, but could not get one working yet

Comment: Edit: thanks anyways, my custom behaviour is working, it just was not working because I was merging layouts...